# Creating OpenCV installer with NSIS

Tags: opencv, installation, inno-setup, nsis, cpack

I am compiling OpenCV for our project with specific build options (such as 64bit, QT and OpenNI). I was able to follow the instruction as given here: http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html

At the end of 2-3 hours of build process, I ended up with `\install\build\` with collected bins, dlls and libs in their respective folder. I would like to distribute an .exe installer to other members in research group. But I could not because `_CPack_Packages/win32/NSIS` is nowhere to be found.

> Note: To create an installer you need to install NSIS. Then just build the
>   Package project to build the installer into the
>   `Build/_CPack_Packages/win32/NSIS` folder. You can then use this to
>   distribute OpenCV with your build settings on other systems.

In the cmake-gui screen, I ticked "Build Package" which I hoped would enable me to see `Build/_CPack_Packages/win32/NSIS` folder. After build process, this is not found.

Could someone give a suggestion as why I don't see this `_CPack_Packages/win32/NSIS` folder as described? Could I use 
[Inno setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) instead? If so, do I simply pack all `\build\install` folder and set path in system to include `\build\install\bin`?
Thank you.

Comment: *Could I use Inno setup instead ?* - I think it should be possible - even OpenCV seems to had some InnoSetup [`script sample`](http://code.opencv.org/svn/opencv/tags/attic/beta3/opencv/utils/opencv.iss) - first Google hit for `InnoSetup OpevCV script`, but the link is dead and I don't know how to search in their repository, maybe you wou'll be more successful. But someone else made [`something`](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/utils/opencv.iss?rev=27) what might you looking for (don't know how recent is this version though, but at least could be inspirative).

Answer (score 2):

Sticking with the KISS principle (Keep it simple, Stupid!):

Did you install NSIS prior to building the *Package* project?

```
INSTRUCTIONS TO BUILD WIN32 PACKAGES WITH CMAKE+CPACK
------------------------------------------------------

- Install NSIS.
- Generate OpenCV solutions for MSVC using CMake as usual.
- In cmake-gui: 
    - Mark BUILD_PACKAGE
    - Mark BUILD_EXAMPLES (If examples are desired to be shipped as binaries...)
    - Unmark ENABLE_OPENMP, since this feature seems to have some issues yet...
- Mark INSTALL_*_EXAMPLES
- Open the OpenCV solution and build ALL in Debug and Release.
- Build PACKAGE, from the Release configuration. An NSIS installer package will be 
  created with both release and debug LIBs and DLLs.


Jose Luis Blanco, 2009/JUL/29
```

I suggest instead of using Visual Studio to build, you should try using CMake.

http://www.cmake.org/

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: I sure did. And I did build both debug and release, and still this '_CPack_Packages/win32/NSIS' is not found. I'm very happy to try this again. Wait... isn't it strange, I don't have 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS' in my PATH?? I will do more tests... thank you for your answer and I will let you know soon.

Comment: I found a package called `package_source` in Visual Studio, but when I press the build with that package highlighted, the terminal gives shows: 
`2>  'zip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
2>  operable program or batch file.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 9009.`

Comment: Downloaded OpenCV and had a look through the documentation and found packaging.txt in the doc directory. I have edited my answer to include it's contents.

Comment: Hi Ryan, I did try that, but I did not see project `PACKAGE`. Thanks for your help. I managed to create an installer by using InnoSetup.